# Meaning of Jenkins multi-branch pipeline failure?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've set up several multi-branch pipeline jobs, and all of them have a similar declarative pipeline. On one of my jobs, I get this. For the life of me I can't figure out what it means. Any clues?

```
FailedConsole Output
16:56:25  [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
16:56:25  Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 10.227.23.xxx/10.227.23.xxx:59718
16:56:25        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1800)
16:56:25        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
16:56:25        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
16:56:25        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1247)
16:56:25        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.steps.GitChangelogStep$1.run(GitChangelogStep.java:326)
16:56:25        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
16:56:25        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
16:56:25        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
16:56:25        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
16:56:25        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
16:56:25        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
16:56:25  se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.exceptions.GitChangelogRepositoryException: master not found in:
16:56:25  Repo: Repository[C:\jenkins\workspace\ature_devops-3-upload-zip-file_4\.git]
16:56:25  HEAD
16:56:25  refs/remotes/origin/development
16:56:25  refs/remotes/origin/feature/devops-3-upload-zip-file
16:56:25  refs/remotes/origin/release/1.4.24
16:56:25  refs/remotes/origin/release/1.4.25
16:56:25  refs/remotes/origin/release/1.4.26
16:56:25  refs/remotes/origin/release/1.4.27
16:56:25  refs/remotes/origin/release/1.4.28
16:56:25  refs/remotes/origin/release/1.4.29
16:56:25  
16:56:25    at se.bjurr.gitchangelog.internal.git.GitRepo.getRef(GitRepo.java:142)
16:56:25    at se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.GitChangelogApi.getChangelog(GitChangelogApi.java:443)
16:56:25    at se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.GitChangelogApi.getChangelog(GitChangelogApi.java:77)
16:56:25    at se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.GitChangelogApi.render(GitChangelogApi.java:99)
16:56:25    at se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.GitChangelogApi.render(GitChangelogApi.java:123)
16:56:25    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.steps.GitChangelogStep.perform(GitChangelogStep.java:407)
16:56:25    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.steps.GitChangelogStep.access$000(GitChangelogStep.java:44)
16:56:25    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.steps.GitChangelogStep$1$1.call(GitChangelogStep.java:322)
16:56:25    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
16:56:25    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
16:56:25    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
16:56:25    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
16:56:25    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
16:56:25    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
16:56:25    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
16:56:25    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:93)
16:56:25    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16:56:25  Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do you have a `master` branch in the **ature_devops-3-upload-zip-file_4** repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stated in the log

> master not found in: 16:56:25  Repo:
> Repository[C:\jenkins\workspace\ature_devops-3-upload-zip-file_4.git]

Jenkins git plugin is unable to find the master branch. You can verify this by manually executing the below command from the path

> C:\jenkins\workspace\ature_devops-3-upload-zip-file_4\

```
git show-ref
```

If you do not see the line

> refs/remotes/origin/master

in the output, then you have a problem with your git repository

Comment: I saw that. We have several repos, and NONE of our them use `master`, but `development` as our main branch (I'm new to the company so IDK why), and this is the only job (so far) that I see with this error. The other repos, with similarly set up Jenkinsfile, don't have this issue. Hence I'm baffled and posted the question.

Comment: Ah I lied to you, this Jenkinsfile does something extra. It calls a function that uses the `gitChangelog` plugin, and I'm assuming that's where it's crashing.

Comment: some git implementations consider master as mandatory. Gitlab doesnt allow to remove master. Github allows removing master with a caveat. Perhaps the git-changelog plugin fails due to this. refer this workaround https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/issues/28

Comment: Yeah for now I put the call in a `try/catch` block just to pass my job, but will try the `git checkout -b master` workaround. This is Bitbucket BTW. Thanks Monish.